# Get data from another database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am currently on one database, `for eg: user`. I am retrieving data from that database. But i need to get data from another database like:

```
mysqli_select_db($link, "first");
$q1="select * from user";
$s1=mysqli_query($link,$q);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($s1))
{
 mysqli_select_db($link, "second");
 $q2="select * from ".$row['name'];
 $s2=mysqli_query($link,$q2);
 echo mysql_num_rows($s2);
}
```

But showing error: `undefined index name`. I think it is because of the database change and the queries.

I could not figure out another way to do this. Can you please say another way to implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: That error means that there's no column named `name` in the `user` table.

Comment: @Barmar it does exist in the table `user` in the `first` database.

Comment: What does `var_dump($row)` show?

Comment: what exactly u want to achieve...

Comment: table user in first database have a field "name" exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You define your query in `$q1` but then call `mysqli_query()` with `$q` which is a different variable and I'm guessing you have a previous query stored in that, which would explain the undefined index notice.

Another problem is you're using the same `$link` variable for two different databases. I suggest storing the first in `$link_first` and the second in `$link_second` to keep them separated.

Answer (score 0):

you should change

```
$s1=mysqli_query($link,$q);
```

to

```
$s1=mysqli_query($link,$q1);
```

because your query is stored in $q1

and you can take

```
mysqli_select_db($link, "second");
```

out of while loop.. why are you selecting the database with every iteartion.. ? Once selected it will be there until you chane it again ...

Comment: I hope `$row[name]` contains the table name that exists in `second` database